# Showing excel data in web page

Tags: javascript

I have a webpage that has two links to download pdf and excel files,

```
 <a onclick="window.open('Files/Creditcard.xlsx')" >Clickhere excel</a>
<a onclick="window.open('Files/Creditcard.pdf')" >Clickhere pdf</a>
```

While clicking on **Clickhere pdf** it is opening in webpage itself, which is the actual requirement. But coming to **Clickhere excel** it is downloading instead of showing in webpage. Is it not possible to show the excel in webpage? If we can, please help..

Thanks Inadvance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the target of your link? 
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp

Comment: I just did some looking around and it seems like it's a browser configuration issue. From what I gather, .pdf files are universally recognized and all the major browsers have a way to handle the files. With Excel files you'll probably have to use a plug-in for viewing it in a browser.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution i found is, save the excel as a webpage(any how i just want to view the content not to download). So that content can be viewed in the webpage it self..